# Why my values are showing to be not present there

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Dialog from '@mui/material/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@mui/material/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@mui/material/DialogContent';
import DialogContentText from '@mui/material/DialogContentText';
import DialogTitle from '@mui/material/DialogTitle';

export default function AdvSearchInvoice() {
const [searcSuccess, setSearchSuccess] = useState(false);
const [formSubmit, setFormSubmit] = useState(false);
const [search, setSearch] = useState(false);
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    doc_id: '',
    invoice_id: '',
    cust_number: '',
    businness_year: ''

});


const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
};

const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
};

const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { label, value } = e.target
    setFormData({ ...formData, [label]: value })
}
const handleFormSubmit = () => {
    setFormSubmit(true)
}
const handleSubmit = () => {
    handleClose();
    handleFormSubmit();
}



return (
    <>
        <Button variant="outlined" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
            Open form dialog
        </Button>
        <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
            <DialogTitle>Subscribe</DialogTitle>
            <DialogContent>
                <form>
                    <TextField
                        autoFocus
                        id="outlined-basic"
                        name="doc_id"
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        value={doc_id}
                        sx={{ mt: 2, mr: 2, backgroundColor: "white", borderRadius: "0.5rem" }}

                        variant="filled"
                    />
                    <TextField
                        autoFocus
                        id="outlined-basic"
                        label="invoice_id"
                        onChange={handleChange(invoice_id)}
                        sx={{ mt: 2, mr: 2, backgroundColor: "white", borderRadius: "0.5rem" }}

                        variant="filled"
                    />
                    <TextField
                        autoFocus
                        id="outlined-basic"
                        label="cust_number"
                        onChange={handleChange(cust_number)}
                        sx={{ mt: 2, mr: 2, backgroundColor: "white", borderRadius: "0.5rem" }}

                        variant="filled"
                    />
                    <TextField
                        autoFocus
                        id="outlined-basic"
                        label="businness_year"
                        onChange={handleChange(businness_year)}
                        sx={{ mt: 2, mr: 2, backgroundColor: "white", borderRadius: "0.5rem" }}

                        variant="filled"
                    />
                </form>
            </DialogContent>
            <DialogActions>
                <Button onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</Button>
                <Button onClick={handleClose}>Cancel</Button>
            </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>
    </>

)
}
```

Why am I getting This error??
"Line 63:19:  'doc_id' is not defined          no-undef
Line 69:34:  'invoice_id' is not defined      no-undef
Line 78:34:  'cust_number' is not defined     no-undef
Line 87:34:  'businness_year' is not defined  no-undef"
I did define it above
can anyone help me to solve this?
I am trying to send this data to the backend by using material ui dialogue box

Answer (score 0):

Because doc_id is field of object formData. Use {formData.doc_id}

https://rossbulat.medium.com/react-native-working-with-objects-aff45bff6832